# Как передать параметр при нажатие на кнопку в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Мне необходимо в localStorage создать объект в котором будут хранится закладки.
Пытался найти какой нибудь гайд, решение ,пример как просто передать параметр при нажатии на кнопку.
Попробовал пример из данного решения (https://learn-reactjs.ru/basics/handling-events) выдает ошибку.

> Cannot read property 'updateMarker' of undefined

Функция обработчик onClick

```
updateMarker(key, value)  {
    console.log('кнопка нажата', key,value)
    // update react state
    this.setState({ [key]: value });
    // update localStorage
    localStorage.setItem(key, value);

}
```

Кнопка которая передает 2 параметра.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <ul className="list-group">
            {
                this.props.items.map(function(item) {
                    console.log(item)
                    return( <div  key={item}>
                        <li className="list-group-item" data-category={item}>{item}</li>
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-dark"  onClick={e => this.updateMarker('newMarker', item)}>Закладки</button>
                    </div> );

                })
            }
        </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: В приведённом коде у вас `updateMarker` не вызывается нигде. Приведите код с ошибкой)

Comment: в приведенном коде стоит обработчик handleSort, вопрос про updateMarker

Comment: @Suvitruf я же написал какая ошибка ) 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateMarker' of undefined
onClick
src/component/List.js:39
  36 |     console.log(item)
  37 |     return( <div  key={item}>
  38 |         <li className="list-group-item" data-category={item}>{item}</li>
> 39 |         <button type="button" className="btn btn-dark"  onClick={e => this.updateMarker('newMarker', item)}>Закладки</button>
  40 |     </div> );
  41 | 
  42 | })

Comment: @DmitryKozlov прошу прощения, эт тестовый обработчик был такая же ошибка была. Изменил описание.

Comment: @Silverfire а попробуйте объявить метод вот так `updateMarker = (key, value) => {` вместо того, что у вас сейчас.

Comment: @Suvitruf не не помогает все та же ошибка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы теряете ваш контекст в этом месте

```
this.props.items.map(function(item) {
```

Попробуйте так

```
this.props.items.map(item => {
```

Comment: А слона я и не приметил )

Comment: А блин это же я взял со старой версии я объявление компонента изменил  ,а вот мапинг нет. Спасибо ))

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал всё написать на es7

```js
updateMarker = (key, value) => { ... }


render() {
  const { items } = this.props;

  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="list-group">
        {
          items.map((item) => { ... })
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```